# Pandas: Drop() int64 based on value returns object

Tags: python, pandas

I need to drop all rows where a one column are below a certain value. I used the command below, but this returns the column as an object. I need to keep it as `int64`:

```
df["customer_id"] = df.drop(df["customer_id"][df["customer_id"] < 9999999].index)
df = df.dropna()
```

I have tried to re-cast the field as `int64` after, but this causes the following error with data from a totally different column:

```
invalid literal for long() with base 10: '2014/03/09 11:12:27'
```

Comment: df["cutomer_id"] = df.drop(df[df["cutomer_id"] < 9999999].index)

Comment: This does not change anything. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with  [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['s', 'd', 'f', 'g'],
                'customer_id':[99999990, 99999997, 1000, 8888]})
print (df) 
   a  customer_id
0  s     99999990
1  d     99999997
2  f         1000
3  g         8888

df1 = df[df["customer_id"] > 9999999].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   a  customer_id
0  s     99999990
1  d     99999997
```

Solution with `drop`, but is slowier:

```
df2 = (df.drop(df.loc[df["customer_id"] < 9999999, 'customer_id'].index))
print (df2)
   a  customer_id
0  s     99999990
1  d     99999997
```

**Timings**:

```
In [12]: %timeit df[df["customer_id"] > 9999999].reset_index(drop=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 676 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit (df.drop(df.loc[df["customer_id"] < 9999999, 'customer_id'].index))
1000 loops, best of 3: 921 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Is it possible to run this on several columns in one command?

Comment: Do you need compare multiple columns for `9999999` ? If yes, data can be excluded if row in all columns contain `9999999` or if at least one of column contains `9999999`?

Comment: E.g. 9999999 for one column and 999 for another? Currently I need to define a series of DFs to capture the changes. I am sure there is a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: Sorry, but you need for each column some different condition? e.g. for column `col1` values higher as `999`, for another `col2` higher as `77777` ant this way for each column? This is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with slicing the whole frame (and reindexing if necessary)?

```
df = df[df["customer_id"] < 9999999]
df.index = range(0,len(df))
```